# Javascript number validation function acting up + constructive criticism wanted

Tags: javascript

So the goal was to make a very simple two field form and use javascript to validate that only numeric values are entered in either field.

Two issues with my code: only the else condition of the functions that follow seems to execute. Even more confusingly it also executes just clicking in the other field when the fields are empty.

Help please?

The Javascript:

```
// 1. Validate that only a numeric value is entered

function validateMin() {

  var min = document.getElementById("min").value;

  if (isNaN(min)) {

    var el1 = document.getElementById("valFailMin");
    el1.textContent = "Ok";

  } else {

    var el1 = document.getElementById("valFailMin");
    el1.textContent = "Only numbers";

  }  

}


function validateMax() {

  var max = document.getElementById("max").value;

  if (isNaN(max)) {

    var el2 = document.getElementById("valFailMax");
    el2.textContent = "Ok";

  } else { 

    var el2 = document.getElementById("valFailMax");
    el2.textContent = "Only numbers please";

  }  

}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="myForm">
      <label for="min">Min</label><input id="min" type="number" placeholder="Type a min value" onblur="validateMin()"/><br>

      <span id="valFailMin"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="myForm">
      <label for="max">Max</label><input id="max" type="number" placeholder="Type a max value" onblur="validateMax()" /><br>

      <span id="valFailMax"></span>
    </div>  

    <div id="valSuccess"></div>

</body>

<script src="validate.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `.value` is a string, not a number. use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: Why do you have two functions to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: Why don't you just us a regular expression instead `/\D/.test(max)` This will return true if it finds a non digit character.

Comment: @markbernard—that will fail for values like '12.5'.

Comment: @DanielA.White It doesn't matter, JS executes [`toNumber()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4) internally when checking the value. There was a valuable comment in the thread (yours?) about empty value coercion, but it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN()` returns `true`, if the checked value *is not a number*, if it is a number, the return value is `false`. Also the argument is [internally coerced](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4) to a number before checking it. In this coercion an empty string is evaluated to `0`, which is a number, hence the check returns `false`.

A fix would be to add a not operator to the condition and detect empty value:

```
if (!isNaN(min) && min !== '') {...}
```

A general way to check, if a variable is a number:

```
var isNumber = (!isNaN(+variable) && isFinite(+variable));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
if (isNaN(min)) {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("valFailMin");
  el1.textContent = "Ok";
```

*isNaN* returns true if the value isn't a number, so this will return "Ok" where *min* isn't a number. Depending on the type of number you are after, a regular expression may be more appropriate:

```
if (/^\d+\.?\d*$/.test(min)) {
  // min is an integer or float
}
```

This will return true for values like '5' or '12.3' but false for valid numbers like '1.23e4'.

The number validation function should be separate from the function to validate the fields, so:

```
function validNumber (value) {
  return /^\d+\.?\d*$/.test(value);
}
```

Then the validation can be something like:

```
function validateNumberField(el) {
  var errField = document.getElementById(el.id + 'Err');
  errField.textContent = validNumber(el.value)? 'Ok' : 'Fail';
}
```

if you pass *this* from the listener and link the id (or name) of the input being checked to its related error field.

Some markup (simplified for posting):

```
Min<input id="min" type="number" placeholder="Type a min value"
onblur="validateNumberField(this)"><br>
<span id="minErr" style="color:red"></span><br>

Max<input id="max" type="number" placeholder="Type a max value"
onblur="validateNumberField(this)"><br>
<span id="maxErr" style="color:red"></span>
```

You may want to allow for an empty value and to remove leading and trailing white.